# Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, html, css

here the code

```
  function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}
```

I got error - Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.

How can fix this.

Comment: can you provide a code sandbox ?

Comment: Interesting, could you please edit your question and add the relevant code, so we actually see it happen? It's missing the corresponding HTML

Comment: x[n].style.display = "block"; // here you have the error . console.log(x) to check what is actually there in x. x[n] doesn't have style here

Comment: please provide a [repro] for debugging details. @scr2em a sandbox alone would not be allowed. A question must be self-containing and provide all necessary code in the question directly as a stacksnippet. Sandbox are only allowed as extensions to that.

Comment: You should avoid to use `.style` function in JS in 2021. The modern approach is to use `.classList` + `.add('class-name')` , `.remove('class-name')` or `.toggle('class-name')` to apply changes through CSS. This causes far less issues incl. possible specificity weight issues.

Comment: @scr2em - Although it may not be obvious, this is actually complete enough that we can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a pain. :-) The problem is that documents can contain both HTML elements ([`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)) and other kinds of elements, so the various DOM methods can only assume the type [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) for what they return, not `HTMLElement`. `Element` doesn't have a `style` property.

Separately, once you resolve the issue with `x[n]`, you'll have an issue with the fact that `getElementById` can return `null`.

If you're only dealing with HTML elements, you might give yourself some convenience wrappers that (at least in dev mode) test the assertion that the results are HTML elements, so you can then assume they are in later code:

Here's a **rough and ready** example:

```typescript
// An assertion type guard that throws if given a non-HTMLElement
function assertHTMLElement(el: Element): asserts el is HTMLElement {
    if (!(el instanceof HTMLElement)) {
        throw new Error(`Element is not an HTML element`);
    }
}

// A "get element by ID" that requires an HTMLElement and that the
// element does exist (never returns `null`)
function gid(id: string): HTMLElement {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el === null) {
        throw new Error(`No element with id "${id}" found`);
    }
    assertHTMLElement(el);
    return el;
}

// A "query selector all" that ensures all matching elements are HTMLElements
function qsa(selector: string): HTMLElement[] {
    const list = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return Array.prototype.map.call(list, el => {
        assertHTMLElement(el);
        return el;
    }) as HTMLElement[];
}
```

Then your code would use them:

```
function showTab(n: number) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    const x = qsa(".tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
        gid("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        gid("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        gid("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
        gid("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEEDtQQwZzgUwE4BcCWB7aqCeAHRUAcwFcZkATUVACxlRtuUwHc5R0AzE9AN0TQYoSNgC0ACQAqAWQAyAUQA2iALaDUAKC6lIAYwzZYCFKmnzlajQApESgFyhL6yKgCUj+EjQc7nDuaKKi6MAN6aoJGcPNYAhLZKnJBwqDD6iJg8gc4abm6g4VFFTCysIohlCsgsyNYABjmu-iKYjGmggaB2Vq51bgDcEVEAvpqjmiAQoABExIiM3SGgAEa4oACSACLTTAygyIgAjqToBxzt2cEasJDUdHt0iBNgi9eUmIi+AB7oKaDWkEQAmQ+3mpGQyVAdUgpCUSj62l0Biw0GI6Eo1nRjhSyHQkGIHg6siCPTCQ0iemwfz8AF5QO89KQQgA6OaoRqoABCuHWGPRA3J0X+tJpdJhcPyhWKkTopXKlWqmFqdQAcpgulcmqx0HRONRpgASULo4Y7LiYXSUPqDIqjIpeUyXUkJAVFA6ocHQOyDcaTcAzY4oNZIFQGJWwOE7e4LZLgz4RxKqBh6Wh44ga0nnA5Eiya1BwRH6QzQQ5wGDWEOIMPIbGoXH4wlOkIAbQAugVBZTkowlL9GHSGUyNMzA8hcABlbrV8BwitT1BK11Rd2eiDVGC4Zn4FgLvCEZlJ-DMvQwWe9lIAGg1oBpAD4O9LIg60E2bHYl9KVxCNTaRvl4DmJItq2PqaIWyJGHAtBsFIMDLACjgwqoywoJKgqTFIqYcDoRYoqA2pwvSvz4EoG5MEQcCEHo3DoIgdxwaAmTkaA5rIKozIcZ2VKMF8N6gKW5bTMyqTLNMH6gF8zaQK2zIpLgKjMpQxGkWsdLTMsSiYHoADW0y-pEIAccyNzUFw6C8Y8oAAAoHHwWCkHAwAqogXyMMspCoAuyT2IK3D-NAoqgAADGhj68Bi0zbkCnKoJAYmyXgClKZRKl8dMoiAnpgrDBqSAPo+aIRVFfAxXFbgJfJiCKcpZFqXivaZfpoB2lEfkAjedLWF8zIqPiupiKAACMeT5dKhXWOlLlcrF8V4oCyCdGp46kMsqg6lltq5UQUpjeiE2Aq5pWzZA82LTMzmuRtIzoWARljJoQA)

Note I've also added a type to `n`, since it was defaulting to `any`.

---

Side note: I'd suggest using classes rather than inline styling.

Comment: *(Oops, I kinda forgot to have the code use the `qsa` function; I'd left some code there doing an inline assertion instead. Hit refresh if you see `const x =` not followed by `qsa(".tab");`.)*